# UWP TileControl with direction right to left

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

By default [UWP TileControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/tilecontrol) allows animate itself from left to right.

It is unclear how to get it working in the opposite direction from right to left?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify a negative value for the AnimationStep Properties.

```
<controls:TileControl x:Name="Tile1" AnimationStepX="-1" AnimationStepY="-1" OffsetX="-10" OffsetY="10" IsAnimated="True"
    ScrollViewerContainer="{x:Bind FlipView}" ParallaxSpeedRatio="1.2"/>
```

Comment: The App store has a sample app where you can download and experiment with changes to values in the XAML ; saving you the time of building a project to experiment.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab